# Qual estrutura JSON utilizar para grande volume de dados, sem perda de desempenho?

Tags: json, desempenho, otimização

Estou pensando em usar JSON em um projeto, pois é altamente aceito e há muitas bibliotecas prontas que o codificam e decodificam em outros objetos (arrays, por exemplo), mas há algo que me preocupa.

Suponha que um Web Service retorne valores de uma tabela de banco de dados chamada `clientes`. Algo assim:

```
"clientes":[
    {"nome":"João", "sobrenome":"Silva"}, 
    {"nome":"José", "sobrenome":"Barbosa"}, 
    {"nome":"Maria", "sobrenome":"Joana"}
]
```

Agora, suponha que a tabela tenha 10 milhões de linhas e eu precise que o Web Service retorne um objeto JSON com todos eles.

O tamanho do objeto seria enorme. Logo, seria necessário muita largura de banda para transferir as informações.

Eu poderia comprimir o objeto JSON usando gzip, mas isto geraria outro problema: um alto custo de processamento para comprimir o objeto.

Eu poderia inventar um formato compacto e simplesmente usá-lo. Mas eu perderia todas as facilidades oferecidas pelas bibliotecas que lidam com objetos JSON. Além disso, seria um projeto fora do padrão, o que o tornaria de difícil manutenção.

Existe uma solução para este dilema?

Eu estava pensando... talvez exista um formato JSON diferenciado que é aceito pelas bibliotecas, e que seja específico para os casos em que os nomes dos dados são constantes.

Por exemplo, algo como isto:

```
"clientes":[
    {$"nome", "sobrenome"$}, 
    {"João", "Silva"}, 
    {"José", "Barbosa"}, 
    {"Maria", "Joana"}
]
```

Existe algo assim?

Se não, qual seria a melhor solução? Eu preciso retornar objetos grandes e gostaria também de usar um formato comum para transferí-los.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se o sistema for muito bem documentado, nada impede de remover tudo que não for necessário e fazer apenas isso:

```
[
    ["João", "Silva"], 
    ["José", "Barbosa"],
    ["Maria", "Joana"]
]
```

(as quebras de linha são apenas para facilitar a leitura).

Se quiser um pouco mais completinha, mantendo todos os dados mas sem redundância:

```
{
   "clientes": [
      "nomes": [ "João", "José", "Anônimo", "Maria" ],
      "sobrenomes": [ "Silva", "Barbosa", "", "Joana" ]
   ]
}
```

Só não pule nenhum parâmetro vazio. Deixe o `""` na posição faltante, para que os nomes não saiam de sincronismo com os sobrenomes.

Ainda, se precisar manter os nomes dos campos separados para consulta, pode ser algo assim:

```
{
   "campos":
   [
       "nome", "sobrenome"
   ],
   "clientes":
   [
       ["João", "Silva"], 
       ["José", "Barbosa"],
       ["Maria", "Joana"]
   ]
}
```

Poderia dividir de outras mil maneiras, mas acredito que com estas como ponto de partida, fica fácil resolver o problema.

Answer (score 7):

Primeiramente, o JSON é um objeto bem compacto, imagine um XML aprimorado, ele é o JSON. Por isso você pode sem problemas incluir muitos e muitos registros sem se preocupar muito com isso, inclusive você realmente não precisa enviar uma **string** contendo o JSON para depois dar **parse** nela e transformar em um objeto JSON, você pode simplesmente enviar o objeto JSON diretamente, a maioria das linguagens hoje em dia suportam isto, então não se preocupe.

Referente a estrutura que você deseja, de forma mais "leve" e sem perder o contexto:

### Recomendo o uso desta:

```
{

    "sobrenome":{
        "cliente":[
            "Silva",
            "Barbosa",
            "Joana"
        ]
    },
    "nome":{
        "cliente":[
            "João",
            "José",
            "Maria"
        ]
    }

}
```

**Mas é muito importante ressaltar as palavras do @Bacco**:

> *Poderia dividir de outras maneiras, mas talvez seja perigoso confundir quando faltar algum parâmetro (teria que deixar o "" na posição faltante, pra não sair de sincronismo):*

```
{
   "nomes": [ "João", "José", "Anônimo", "Maria" ],
   "sobrenomes": [ "Silva", "Barbosa", "", "Joana" ]
}
```

### Mas porque eu deveria usar esta estrutura?

Porque desta forma há apenas Array's de dados e não um Array com *label's* e dados (causando duplicidade de *label* a cada registro), como por exemplo um array com *labels* e dados:

```
{

    "cliente":[
        {
            "nome":"João",
            "sobrenome":"Silva"
        },
        {
            "nome":"José",
            "sobrenome":"Barbosa"
        },
        {
            "nome":"Maria",
            "sobrenome":"Joana"
        }
    ]

}
```

Note, que o **"nome"** e o **"sobrenome"** se repetem a cada registro, em um objeto enorme como o seu, isto acarretaria um problema maior na performance.

### Adicional:

Já que você mencionou **Web Service** primeiramente acredito que você possa armazenar seu json em um arquivo extensão `.json` contendo apenas o json dentro. E posso imaginar que você tenha a possibilidade de trabalhar com javascript, por isto te recomendo utilizar o [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) do jQuery que nada mais é do que uma requisição para o servidor que pode requisitar um JSON diretamente, como por exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "arquivoJSON.json"
}).done(function(){
  alert( "sucesso" );
}).fail(function(){
  alert( "erro" );
});
```

E também existe um método [shorthand](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/) do jQuery chamado [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) que facilitaria ainda mais a requisição:

```
$.getJSON("arquivoJSON.json", function( json ) {
  console.log("Nome: "      + json.nome.cliente[0]);      //João
  console.log("Sobrenome: " + json.sobrenome.cliente[0]); //Silva
});
```

## Conclusão:

O JSON é a maneira mais leve de resgatar dados encapsulados do servidor, tanto é que é uma tecnologia desenvolvida com este intuito, de substituir o XML na maioria dos casos, e por ser uma tecnologia utilizada para WEB e aplicações WEB precisarem de desempenho e velocidade em questão da internet do usuário, ele realmente se sai bem. Não importa muito a linguagem que você estiver utilizando, basta estar resgatando um objeto JSON de forma direta e com uma estrutura bem pensada, que você não vai ter grandes problemas com performance e desempenho.

Answer (score 4):

Para sistemas de alto desempenho que necessitam de troca de dados através de um protocolo reconhecido porém flexível, JSON não é a melhor solução. Note que não estou falando de um sistema web que acessa dados do servidor via JavaScript.

Existem várias soluções para troca de mensagens em formatos que, em relação ao JSON, consomem menos tempo para serialização/deserialização e menos banda.

Um deles é o formato [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/). Ele nada mais é do que o JSON Binário (*Binary JSON*). A proposta é ser mais leve e eficiente que o JSON, mantendo a flexibilidade e compatibilidade. Existem [implementações para praticamente todas as linguagens](http://bsonspec.org/implementations.html).

Embora o BSON seja eficiente, existem alguns cenários onde este formato ocupa mais espaço para armazenamento ou em memória que o JSON. Veja [esta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12611616/1683070) para mais detalhes.

Outra alternativa mais compacta e rápida que o JSON é o formato [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/). Ele também possui implementações para a maioria das linguagens.

Particularmente, eu faria alguns testes com o MessagePack antes de decidir qualquer coisa.

Comment: +1 por desmistificar JSON como sendo formato mais compacto, entre outras coisas.