# Consumir WebService com grande volume de dados

Tags: android, json, web-service

Tenho uma demanda onde preciso importar um arquivo `JSON` com 65k de registros para meu app `Android`,após chamar a URL do meu serviço `REST` o app começa a importar os dados porém trava depois de algum tempo, gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma para se trabalhar com grande volume de dados em aplicações mobile.

Alguns pontos:

- Eu teria que dividir este arquivo?

Hoje ele está assim :

```
[{"codigoTabela":0,"codigoProduto":"623261","vendaAtual":83.4012,"vendaOferta":0.0000,"dataInicioOferta":"Jan 1, 1900","dataFimOferta":"Jan 1, 1900","totalRegistros":62314},
```

Tem como otimizar este modelo?

**Nota:** Esse app funciona normalmente com volume de dados menores.

Comment: Olá creio que isso possá lhe ajudar,

[http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40404/qual-estrutura-json-utilizar-para-grande-volume-de-dados-sem-perda-de-desempenh][1]


  [1]: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40404/qual-estrutura-json-utilizar-para-grande-volume-de-dados-sem-perda-de-desempenh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Versão simples: Segmente seu resultado usando paginação. Existem várias maneiras de implementar este mecanismo, um exemplo segue abaixo.

Em vez de mandar 60k registros, implemente um processo que:

1. Armazene o resultado da sua busca temporariamente no servidor;
2. Mande 5k registros, mais um objeto indicado qual 'página' dos dados você está vendo (zero no caso), e que ainda existem páginas aguardando fetch no servidor;
3. Faça seu client obter mais registros (página + 1);
4. Repita 2 e 3 até esgotar o número de páginas;
5. Elimine o conteúdo temporário armazenado no servidor.

Um exemplo de JSON com controle de paginação:

```
{
    results: [{},{},...{}],
    page: 0,
    continue: true
}
```

Repita as solicitações, e retorne `continue: false` quando o conteúdo se esgotar no servidor.